# Python GUI Using a menu option to change the GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to learn making a GUI using python. I am trying to use a menu system to then have one of the menu options call a function to update the GUI. However instead of when pressing the menu option the GUI updates the GUI is already calling the function on launch.

Heres is my current code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()

def db_insert():
    Label(root,text='Item Name: ').grid(row=0)
    Label(root,text='Item Cost: ').grid(row=1)
    Label(root,text='Item Quantity: ').grid(row=2)
    e1 = Entry(root)
    e2 = Entry(root)
    e3 = Entry(root)
    e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    e3.grid(row=2,column=1)

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label='Insert',command=db_insert())
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label='Exit',command=root.quit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=db_insert()` calls the function *right now*, and uses its return value (probably `None`) as the command to execute when the button is clicked.  You don't want those parentheses here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonharper said, you don't want the parenthesis when passing a function for a callback, like you did with your exit command command.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def db_insert():
    tk.Label(root,text='Item Name: ').grid(row=0)
    tk.Label(root,text='Item Cost: ').grid(row=1)
    tk.Label(root,text='Item Quantity: ').grid(row=2)
    e1 = tk.Entry(root)
    e2 = tk.Entry(root)
    e3 = tk.Entry(root)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label='Insert', command=db_insert) # <-- Removed parenthesis
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.quit)

root.mainloop()
```